# Datatables nested table error 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Im trying to make a simple nested table using jquery datatables. but now i only got 404 error in console window after clicking the main row to expand the detais part.  on click the id in the row should assignrd to detais tables ajax request and it should return data.  any guesses ?

Thanks a Lot in Advance.

My Html

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Item 1</th>
        <th>Item 2</th>
        <th>Item 3</th>
        <th>Item 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {


    <tr data-child-value="hidden 1">
        <td class="details-control"></td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IO_ID)
        </td>

        <th>

            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.PO_IO_TOPIC)
        </th>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PO_IOU_Client)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PO_IO_DOC_NO)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
```

My Jquery with nested table

```
 var dd; // to pass header row data to detail table
    function format(name, value) {
        return '<div><table id="example1" cellspacing="0" width="90%">'+
           ' <thead>' +
            '<tr>' + 
            '<th></th>' +
           '<th>CI 1</th>' +
            '<th>CI 2</th>' + 
             '</tr>'+ 
           '</thead></table></div>';
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({});

        // Add event listener for opening and closing details
        $('#example').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);

            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            } else {

                row.child(format(tr.data('child-value'))).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }
            alert(table.cell(this, 1).data());
            dd = table.cell(this, 1).data();  // asign header id to variable
            var table1 = $('#example1').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "PO_Trn_IOU/IocollectionPickup",
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "data": dd , // assign header row id to get detail data

                } });


        });

    });
```

Controller

```
  public JsonResult IocollectionPickup(string data)
    {

        POPM_TRN_IOUColection pop = new POPM_TRN_IOUColection();

        var iocollection = 
                            from c in db.PO_TR_IOColection
                            where c.IOID == Convert.ToInt16(data)
                            select new
                            {                              
                                docno = c.Collection_DocNumber,
                                date = c.date
                            };

        return Json(iocollection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this part `"url": "PO_Trn_IOU/IocollectionPickup",` making sure it's a valid url - you may need to specify full path)

Comment: FYI: You have a repetetive `<th>`  in each row of your  `<tbody>` section.

Comment: differenced i corrected cos i have made some changes to the original code after past here. code is fine and the url is correct. what im not sure is that return data matches with the detail table like colum count should equel datas . is that could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the ASP.NET Fiddler link https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ilIUT  to see it works

Here I got it to work, so you can compare and figure out what you did wrong.  Pay attention to the comments.  I will post a JSFiddler type link for ASP.NET, so you can click on a link and see it work.

cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Testy20161006.Controllers.RangeDataView>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index62</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dd; // to pass header row data to detail table
        function format(name, value) {
            return '<div id="addToMe" ><table id="example1" cellspacing="0" width="90%">' +
               ' <thead>' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<th></th>' +
               '<th>CI 1</th>' +
                '<th>CI 2</th>' +
                 '</tr>' +
               '</thead>';
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({});
            // Add event listener for opening and closing details
            $('#example').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);

                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                } else {
                    row.child(format(tr.data('child-value'))).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
                dd = table.cell(this, 1).data();  // asign header id to variable
                var table1 = $('#example1').DataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "bProcessing": false,
                    "ajax": {
                        //!changed this url to hit my home controller also prefacing with /
                        //"url": "PO_Trn_IOU/IocollectionPickup",
                        "url": "/Home/IocollectionPickup",
                        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        //!adding the brackets and title matching c# action
                        "data": { "theData": dd }, // assign header row id to get detail data
                        "dataType": "json",
                        "asynch": false,
                        "success": function (theData) {
                            var tbody = $('#example1 tbody')
                            $.each(theData, function (index, value) {
                                var row = $("<tr>");
                                row.append($("<td>").text(value.date));
                                row.append($("<td>").text(value.docno));
                                tbody.append(row);
                            });
                        }
                    },
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tempShow" />
    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Item 1</th>
                <th>Item 2</th>
                <th>Item 3</th>
                <th>Item 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr data-child-value="hidden 1">
                    @*adding the click here so user has something to click into*@
                    <td class="details-control">Click Here to Run Ajax</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IO_ID)
                    </td>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.PO_IO_TOPIC)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PO_IOU_Client)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PO_IO_DOC_NO)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        @*You were missing a table end tag*@
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

code

```
//namespace Testy20161006.Controllers
public class RangeDataView
{
    public string IO_ID { get; set; }
    public string PO_IO_TOPIC { get; set; }
    public string PO_IOU_Client { get; set; }
    public string PO_IO_DOC_NO { get; set; }
}

public class POPM_TRN_IOUColection
{
    public string docno { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult IocollectionPickup(string theData) //!change parm name
    {
        //you can put a breakpoint here and see theData contains the value passed through ajax

        //MOCKING Data so I can show you

        //POPM_TRN_IOUColection pop = new POPM_TRN_IOUColection();

        //var iocollection =
        //                    from c in db.PO_TR_IOColection
        //                    where c.IOID == Convert.ToInt16(data)
        //                    select new
        //                    {
        //                        docno = c.Collection_DocNumber,
        //                        date = c.date
        //                    };

        List<POPM_TRN_IOUColection> iocollection = new List<POPM_TRN_IOUColection>();
        POPM_TRN_IOUColection item1 = new POPM_TRN_IOUColection { date = "3/5/68", docno = "doc1" };
        POPM_TRN_IOUColection item2 = new POPM_TRN_IOUColection { date = "3/5/69", docno = "doc2" };
        iocollection.Add(item1);
        iocollection.Add(item2);

        return Json(iocollection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult Index127()
    {
        List<RangeDataView> dv = new List<RangeDataView>();
        RangeDataView item1 = new RangeDataView { IO_ID = "1", PO_IO_DOC_NO = "DOC1", PO_IO_TOPIC = "TOPIC1", PO_IOU_Client = "CLIENT1" };
        RangeDataView item2 = new RangeDataView { IO_ID = "2", PO_IO_DOC_NO = "DOC2", PO_IO_TOPIC = "TOPIC2", PO_IOU_Client = "CLIENT2" };
        RangeDataView item3 = new RangeDataView { IO_ID = "3", PO_IO_DOC_NO = "DOC3", PO_IO_TOPIC = "TOPIC3", PO_IOU_Client = "CLIENT3" };
        RangeDataView item4 = new RangeDataView { IO_ID = "4", PO_IO_DOC_NO = "DOC4", PO_IO_TOPIC = "TOPIC4", PO_IOU_Client = "CLIENT4" };
        dv.Add(item1);
        dv.Add(item2);
        dv.Add(item3);
        dv.Add(item4);
        return View(dv);
    }
```

Comment: no words to thanks mate . even the .net fiddle i never knew about it . I owe you . Thanks a lot